# How to render DOT file using only pos attributes

Tags: python, dot, pydot

I have taken an initial DOT file and modified the pos attributes of some nodes using pydot. Now I want to render an image file that shows the nodes in their new positions. The catch is, I *don't* want a layout program to mess with the positions! I just want to see the nodes exactly where the pos attribute indicates. I don't care about how the edges look.

I can produce a DOT file with my positions easily using pydot, but I can't figure out how to make an image file, either in pydot or on the command line with dot. Help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dot.write_png('filename.png')`? Or is there something I'm missing?

Also, the `neato` command-line program has a `-n` option for graph files that already have layout. The program description says it is for undirected graphs, but I tried it with a digraph and it produced the correct result.

Comment: The problem with `dot.write_png('filename.png')` is that pydot uses a default layout to render the image file. Even with `dot.write_png('filename.png', prog=None)`, I get the default layout.